# How to measure execution time in a shell script in Python?

Tags: python, shell

I created this sh script and want to measure time spent on the program:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=`date +%s`

cd nlu/creator
python3 move_file.py  ../../../../../base_data/   ../../resources/kb/

python3 converter.py
python3 transformer.py

cd  ../../resources/kb/
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs  -I{} rm -rf {}
find . -name '*Object.txt' | xargs  -I{} rm -rf {}

end =`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start))

echo "Building time: ${runtime}"
```

I execute:

```
nlu/creator/builder.sh
```

The error message is:

```
nlu/creator/builder.sh: line 15: end: command not found
Building time: -1651032434
```

why does it complain about 'end:command not found'?

Also, why is the time a negative number? I am on a Mac.

Comment: Remove the space in `end =`, ie make it `end=`.

Answer (score 3):

> why does it complain?

This is general shell script syntax:

In general, `P X Y` runs the command `P` with the two arguments `X` and `Y`. Similarily, `end = something` runs the command `end` with the two arguments `=` and `something`.

Assignment is done by `VAR=VALUE`, for instance

```
end=something
```

If you one day need to execute a command named `end=something` (i.e. not treat it as assignment, you still can do it by writing

```
'end=something'
```

BTW: If you are only interested in knowing the time and are not picky about a particular format of how the time is printed, you could also remove your timing calculation from the script completely, and run the script with the `time` builtin:

```
time nlu/creator/builder.sh
```

Give it a try!